# show that $x^{2013} - 78x^4 +x -1$ has a root in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra

my attempt:

by fundamental theorem of algebra $f(x) = (x-\lambda_1)...(x-\lambda_r)$ with $\lambda_i \in \mathbb{C}$

we know if $\lambda_i$ is a root then so is $\bar{\lambda_i}$, so I just have to show that $\bar{\lambda_i} = \lambda_i$ but im not sure how to do this

Comment: Every odd-degree real polynomial has a real root, it is just a matter of continuity.

Comment: Each complex root has a conjugate complex root, as you correctly guessed, so there are even complex roots. The number of roots by the fundamental theorem of algebra is? (if the same root comes twice or more, just count it twice or more ;-))

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Intermediate value theorem.  If $P(x)=x^{2013}-78x^4+x-1$, what is $P(0)$? What is $P(2)$?

In general, this is true for any polynomial of odd degree.

Comment: I am not sure of the intermediate value thorem, I'm looking for answers continuing on from my attempt if you could please

Comment: @rooftophouse Your solution is over-complicated. Either you take $P(0)$ and $P(2)$ as mentionned or limit at $\pm \infty$, these are easier and more elegant solutions.

Comment: But I came here to get help on my solution..

Comment: If OP doesn't have IVT to use, only the fundamental theorem of algebra, that's what he has to work with. I'm leaving this answer as is, because it answers the question as posed - but I certainly hope someone helps him through his argument.

Comment: @rooftophouse You didn't actually ask for how to continue your answer, just that this was the approach you started with. That said, I hope somebody helps you with your approach.

Answer (score 2):

By the fundamental theorem of algebra you have $2013$ roots.

For every complex root $\lambda_i$, $\bar \lambda_i$ is also a root.

You have then an even number of non-real roots. Since $2013$ is odd, at least one of the root is real.

Comment: I don't understand, since 2013 is odd, at least one is real? isn't that what i want to prove

Comment: The point here is that if you assume all the roots are complex, only up to 2012 of them can have nonzero imaginary parts. The last one must be real because the conjugate of a real number is that same real number.

Comment: I'm asking why only up to 2012 of them can have nonzero imaginary parts? why must last one be real

Comment: Consider a simpler example of a cubic polynomial $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$. By the FTA you can factorize it into three linear factors $a(x-\lambda_1)(x-\lambda_2)(x-\lambda_3)$. If you know one of these roots to have a nonzero imaginary part, then you immediately know that another root is its conjugate pair. The third root cannot be complex with nonzero imaginary part because it does not have a conjugate pair. This is assuming $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$. It comes down to odd numbers not being divisible by $2$.

Comment: I understand that, but I'm asking, how do we know that there is at least one real root, I understand that complex roots come in pairs, and that we wil lalways have one real root for an odd degree polynomial but I'm trying to prove it here